# Codeigniter - Problem displaying result in the view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having problems displaying results of students in my view. The results are successfully stored in the database but I can't seem to be able to show the result.

---

### *controller*

---

```
public function view($id)
    {
if (!$this->rbac->hasPrivilege('student', 'can_view')) {
access_denied();
        }

if($class_id == 2 || $class_id == 3)
        {
$subjectScores = $this->student_model->getRecentGradesRN($id);
        }
        else
        {
$subjectScores = $this->student_model->getRecentGrades($id);
        }

$data['subjectScores'] = $subjectScores;
//var_dump($subjectScores); die();

 $this->load->view('layout/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('student/studentShow', $data);
        $this->load->view('layout/footer', $data);
    }
```

---

### *view*

---

```
<tbody>
                            <?php $i = 1;
                            $total = 0;
                            $count = count($subjectScores);
                            foreach ($subjectScores as $value) { ?>
                                <?php
                                $total += $tot_score;
                                ?>

                                <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;font-size:12px;white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $CI->GetSubjectNameWithID($value->subject_id); ?></td>
                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;font-size:12px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $value->ca1; ?></td>
                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;font-size:12px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $value->ca2; ?></td>
                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;font-size:12px;white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $value->ca3; ?></td>

                                </tr>
                                <?php $i++;
                            } ?>
                            </tbody>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: @sauhardnc no errors

Comment: @MamaJardel is `GetSubjectNameWithID` a custom library?

Comment: @sauhardnc please see my modified view code again

Comment: @MamaJardel your code looks alright and it should work. Does your view show table rows without values or does it not show any row at all?

Comment: It doesn't show any rows at all

Comment: @MamaJardel Ok, try removing `$CI->GetSubjectNameWithID('bla bla)` and see if it works without it

Comment: it didn't work .

Comment: @MamaJardel That's weird, are you sure you're loading the correct `view` and `$subjectScores` is not `empty`?

Comment: yes I'm sure. It was working fine at first. I don't know what went wrong

Comment: @MamaJardel Quite frankly, everything looks good enough, the only thing that is bothering me is this line - `$total += $tot_score;` Probably `$tot_score` is not defined anywhere (at least not in the code shared) or if it is the value from `DB` then it should be `$value->tot_score`. Other than that, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not getting any output because you're storing the result in `$subjectScores` but using `$value` to get the data.

Try using -

```
foreach($subjectScores as $subjectScore){ // foreach to loop the data

    $subjectScore->subject_id;
    $subjectScore->ca1;
    $subjectScore->ca2;
    $subjectScore->ca3;
}
```

See if it helps you.